# DBUnit PostgresqlDataTypeFactory does not recognizes enum list

Tags: java, postgresql, enums, integration-testing, dbunit

I'm using DBUnit for an integration test, and before executing the test code I'm running into this error:

```
badges.track_types data type (2003, '_text') not recognized and will be ignored. See FAQ for more information.

org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: badges.TRACK_TYPES -  (Non-uppercase input column: track_types) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
```

the column that is ignored is a list of enums.
In the dataset it's written like this :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  // More info ...
  <badges name="30&apos;000" description="30k a day" image_name="30000.png" threshold_val="30000.00000000" has_many="true" id="45" track_types="{TRACK_GENERIC}" "/> 
</dataset>
```

I looked in the DBUnit FAQ and saw [this issue](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/dbunit/faq.html#postgresqlEnumTypes) , that says that I have to override the isEnumType() method to support my enum is Postgresql, so I did this:

```
/**
 * Override method to set custom properties/features
 */
protected void setUpDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig config) {

    config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new PostgresqlDataTypeFactory(){
        public boolean isEnumType(String sqlTypeName) {
            if(sqlTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("track_types")){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_METADATA_HANDLER, new DefaultMetadataHandler());
}
```

But I still get the same error, and I don't know why. Maybe I'm not overriding well the method? Maybe it's not even the cause of my problem?
If you need any other code just ask, thanks!

Comment: Does your dataset `badges` contain a column `TRACK_TYPES`?

Comment: Can you send me your source code ? I'll try to dig into it.

Comment: @KevinWallis I just updated the question so you can see the dataset row. Yes, it contains that column, but it's ignored as the error states.

Comment: @IvanUrsul What do you need exactly? That's the source code involved in the problem, I have no problem in sharing it, but just let me know the part you need so I don't make the question so big. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I wasn't able to solve this exactly but managed to solve it by a workaround.

This error comes because of the @DatabaseSetup annotation. If I did this process without using it, it still throws a 'column not recognized' error, because it doesn't recognize postgres arrays (that was the root cause that I have) but I could solve it by creating a new DataTypeFactory that extends from the default one:

```
public class PsqlArrayDataTypeFactory extends DefaultDataTypeFactory {
        public DataType createDataType(int sqlType, String sqlTypeName) throws DataTypeException {
            if (sqlType == Types.ARRAY)
            {
                return DataType.VARCHAR;
            }

            return super.createDataType(sqlType, sqlTypeName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to persist the enum with its value

```
enum.values();
```

it return an array than you save this element

Comment: where should I persist the enum? In the setUpDatabaseConfig method?

Comment: Try to use an `EntityManager ` it has a `persist(obj)` methods

Answer (score 2):

I had next error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "status" is of type topic_status but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

`DbUnit` requests meta for table and receives a type `VARCHAR` for enums from PostgreSQL. But PostgreSQL won't accept this type back.

I overrode methods from `PostgresqlDataTypeFactory` in next way:

```
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, 
    new PostgresqlDataTypeFactory() {
        @Override
        public boolean isEnumType(String sqlTypeName) {
            return "topic_status".equalsIgnoreCase(sqlTypeName);
        }

        @Override
        public DataType createDataType(int sqlType, String sqlTypeName) throws DataTypeException {
            if (isEnumType(sqlTypeName)) {
                sqlType = Types.OTHER;
            }
            return super.createDataType(sqlType, sqlTypeName);
        }
    });
);
```

This sets type for enum as `OTHER` and parent method `super.createDataType(sqlType, sqlTypeName)` creates `DataType` in proper way.

PostgreSQL version: 9.6.5
DbUnit version: 2.5.4

More information could be found on [discussion](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/sql-type-reported-for-enum-td5862561.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is limited support for postgresql enums because only reading and writing strings is supported since dbunit 2.4.6. To do so you have to override the method "isEnumType" in the PostgresqlDataTypeFactory like this:

```
PostgresqlDataTypeFactory factory = new PostgresqlDataTypeFactory(){
  public boolean isEnumType(String sqlTypeName) {
    if(sqlTypeName.equalsIgnoreCase("abc_enum")){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```